# Using spline transformation in gbm function in R

Tags: r, spline, gbm, bspline, boosting

I am trying to use spline transformation(bs function) in the boosting algorithm in R. (gbm function). However, when I write the following code it throws me an error:

```
gbm(as.integer(cancel) ~ bs(log_tenure), data = train, distribution = "bernoulli")
```

Error in data.matrix(x) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Is there any way I can use spline transformations in gbm function in R?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can actually run the code to see what's happening.

Comment: Provide an example, of yor data, please.

Comment: the GBM algorithm is invariant to the scale of the variable, only order of the values of the variable is important. So you don't need to apply spline.